# Parse - Array Value Deletion

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to run some cloud code in Parse that will allow me to check if my submissions from people are older than an hour, and if so, delete them.

In my swift file for the app I have:

```
for object in objects! {
    let newstring = NSString(format: "%.0f", self.slider.value)
    let newtimestamp = date
    object.addObject(newstring, forKey: "times")
    object.addObject(newtimestamp, forKey: "timestamp")
    object.saveInBackground()
}
```

And so I have two separate array's (times and timestamp) and I want to delete from both of them.

My JavaScript knowledge and how it works with Parse's cloud code isn't the strongest. I was thinking something along the lines of this logic, I just can't put it into the syntax / I'm not sure if it's able to be put in the syntax.

```
var old = true
var i = 0
var j = 0

while(old){
    if(currentTime >= timeStamp[i] + 3600) {
        i++
        j++
    }
    else {
        delete timeStamp [0,i--]
        delete times [0,j--]
        old = false
    }
}
```

That's my idea of the logic behind the delete function. I'm assuming I need a run background job for a one minute interval. I'm guessing it has something to do with a `splice` in JS, but not sure.

Any ideas on how to do this? Anything would be **much appreciated**.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting something in a javascript  array is like this `array.splice(index,1)` deletes one element at `index`.

for example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.splice(2,1); //[3]
console.log(arr); // [1,2,4,5];
```

If you want to delete something at the end of an array:

```
arr.pop(); //5
console.log(arr); // [1,2,4];
```

Comment: So what happens if I want to delete more than one value within the array? Almost like the logic in my original post suggests. For example, I have two values that were submitted at the same time, how can I delete that?

Comment: the ,1 `in arr.splice(index,1)` 1 is the number of elements you want to delete in front of `index`. if you did `[1,2,3,4,5].splice(2,2)`, the array would now be `[1,2,5]`(deleted 3 and 4).

Comment: So I can set that value to `i--` or `j--` depending on which array I'm deleting from?

Comment: if you want to delete `i--` amount of elements and `j--` amount of elements then yes, that is correct.